# Kettle / Pentaho Data Integration - unable to create a Database Connection (XulException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException)

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

Having finally got kettle to start and not hang, I still cannot use it to much avail, as when I try to create a new Database Connection (after creating a new Transformation) I get this error:

```
org.pentaho.ui.xul.XulException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Thereafter, I get this more general error for the same actions:

```
General error in dialog
```

In order to get the first 'java...TargetException' again, I have to close and restart kettle.
Note, this also happens when I load an existing kettle job and try to edit its database connection.

Could this be a configuration issue? A missing or misplaced file ? What is the Target that is failing to be Invoked?
Thanks in advance for your help.

#### My config:

macos 10.12.6 (Sierra) 
Pentaho Data Integration (or kettle) 7.1.0 
java version "9.0.4"

Answer (score 11):

As I found out from the Pentaho Data Integration forum, it was a matter of my version of Java.

I uninstalled Java 9 and installed Java 8 and then no longer got this error.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `.kettle` directory in your home directory. In this directory, you may have a `db-cache-<some.numbers>` file. If that is the case: stop spoon, delete the db-cache file, and restart spoon.

If it doesn't work, an other file in that directory may be corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, @AlainD. Actually, switching from Java 9 to Java 8 did the trick. I no longer got this error after.
Note, when I first read your answer, I had no `db-cache-<some.numbers>` file in my `.kettle` folder. I only had 3 simple files.
Now that I got kettle to work and used it a little, I have 7 files there, including `db.cache-7.1.0.0-12`.
Thank anyway. Your answer is still noteworthy for a new user like me learning about this environment, for future issues.

Comment: This db cache is to speed up Kettle in searching the databases tables, column names, column types,... When something changes in the database schema, this cache needs to be re-synchronized. Which you can do from the top menu `Tools/Database/Clear cache`. You can just delete them.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Pentaho Components Reference](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Setup/Components_Reference), Only Java 8 is supported by Pentaho Data Integration, So it is not recommended to try out Java 9 or Java 11 at the moment (until they release a version which supports above Java 8).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=<jdk-1.8> path to environment variable.
This addition has resolved my issue.