# Pentaho - Unable to create a database connection

Tags: java, macos, pentaho, kettle

When I go to create a Database Connection in Kettle I am getting the exact same errors as in this question: [Kettle / Pentaho Data Integration - unable to create a Database Connection (XulException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419828/kettle-pentaho-data-integration-unable-to-create-a-database-connection-xule)

> org.pentaho.ui.xul.XulException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

And after clicking OK there is this message:

> General error in dialog

The difference for me being that I seem to be using the correct Java. I have upgraded to PDI 9.1 and according to the documentation Java 8 is still the only supported Java.

My Config:

- MacOS 10.15.7 (Catalina)
- Pentaho Data Integration (or Kettle) 9.1.0.0-324
- Java jdk1.8.0_161.jdk

What else have I tried?

- I cleared my cache as described in the comments below.
- I updated my SWT as described in this tread: [PDI will not start under MacOS Catalina 10.15](https://community.hitachivantara.com/s/question/0D52S00008BUAViSAP/pdi-will-not-start-under-macos-catalina-1015)
- I changed my Java 8 build to jkd1.8.0_202.jdk per this thread: [Issue while accessing DB Connections- PDI 8](https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-16801)

Comment: can you delete pdi\system\karaf\caches\ everything inside this caches folder and re-launch the tool and try.

Comment: I tried this as well as updating SWT but I still have the problem.

Comment: @PierreDelecto Can you try other jdk 8_xx versions?  Try  jdk1.8.0_202.jdk as someone in this https://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-16801 had luck with using.

Comment: @SusanMustafa I tried build 202 but I am still getting the same error

Comment: @PierreDelecto what does java -version give you?

Comment: @PierreDelecto Just curious if you have more than 1 version of the JDK installed on your mac?  Uninstall All and leave only the  jdk1.8.0_202.jdk for macOS

Comment: @SusanMustafa I actually did uninstall before I tried 202. $ java -version java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: @PierreDelecto I know it might not be what you want, but could you try with Pentaho 8?  I really dont know why else it wouldnt work...but no harm in trying if you could?

Comment: same problem here on Big Sur 11.2